# caroufredsel image slider does not show images if they be within <a></a> tags

Tags: image, hyperlink, slider, caroufredsel

I've used **Caroufredsel** in my website as an image slider.

I want to make it like the first example in

```
<a href="http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/">http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/</a>
```

but whenever I put images withing `<a></a>` tags, slider **disappears**. As I remove `<a></a>` tags, everything runs fine.

How can I make images `clickable` to direct to another page in **Caroufredsel**?

Answer (score 4):

CarouFredSel operates on block-level elements with set height/width. `<a></a>` tags are inline-elements. I recommend surrounding the `<a></a>` tags with `<div></div>` tags and styling the `<div></div>` tags to have a set height/width, display:block and float:left. This has worked for me:

```
#carouselWrapper div {
display: block;
float: left;
width: 500px;
height: 200px;
}
```

Then call the jCarouFredSel initiator on `#carouselWrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

No need to add the extra div element - simply set your `<a>` elements to `display: block`.

```
#carousel a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```